# Posts not being returned in Wordpress search filter

Tags: wordpress, posts, meta

I'm writing a Wordpress query to filter search results.

I want to remove results using the templates `logged_in_mentor_only_template.php`, `logged_in_only_template.php` (and also from two restricted categories).

This query works BUT stops any posts being returned. Very odd, pages are returned but posts are not. (I haven't added the category filtering yet as I have no posts to filter!)

I've tried adding post_type filter with posts and pages listed but still nothing.

Any help appreciated.

```
 query_posts(array_merge($wp_the_query->query, array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'logged_in_mentor_only_template.php',
            'compare' => '!='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'logged_in_only_template.php',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
    )
)));
```

Comment: For your search results, are you only looking for Posts to be returned? Or do you wish to display Pages also, that do not have the meta values specified above?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply, I want to return posts and pages.

Comment: Ok, off the top of my head then, I believe the only way to do this currently is with a Custom Select Query. I'll have a think, and post an answer if a way of doing it comes to mind.

Comment: A preformance Tip: **NEVER** use `query_posts` use `WP_Query` more information: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts & http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts?newsletter=1&nlcode=66447|9502

Comment: Thanks JanW - Apologies for the delay I've offline for a reboot. I'll take a look at redoing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You search for `_wp_page_template` Posts won't have any `_wp_page_template`.
So it will only get pages. Because it will return only post/pages which have a `_wp_page_template` set.
So you need to check for a non existing meta key.

In WP 3.5 the [compare](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) value 'NOT EXISTS' will be added.

Until 3.5 I would suggest the following work around.
Don't add these meta query  values. But check for them in the loop:

```
while (the_posts()): the_post();
    if (get_post_meta(GET_THE_ID(), '_wp_page_template', true) == 'logged_in_mentor_only_template.php' || get_post_meta(GET_THE_ID(), '_wp_page_template', true) == 'logged_in_mentor_only_template.php')
        continue; // skipp the rest of this round
    //Do the rest of your loop
endwhile;
```

A second option would be to get all the post that **do** have the templates.
Get all the ID's from this query.
Then do a new wp_query where you exclude the ID's of the previously fetched query.

**best option**
These work arounds Are not good for performance.
The best option would be to wait a few weeks for WP 3.5, it should be released somewhere in december.

Comment: So you think I need to add a key that applies to posts to bring them into the loop?

I'm not sure what meta information is available about a post?

Comment: That won't work, it will still fail because it won't pass the `_wp_page_template` check :(

Comment: Thanks JanW - I'll take a look at those now. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks JanW, just re-read the response. Can you give me a clue how I would use the 'Not Exists' value? (when its available).

Maybe I'll wait for 3.5?

Comment: you would use the `NOT EXISTS` in an extra `meta_query` It would be the value of the 'compare' argument. You will still need to wait for 3.5 which is expected in a few weekd. ps you can give thanks with the upvote ;)

Comment: Thanks for this JanW, I'll be revisiting it shortly. (sadly, I don't have enough rep to upvote this answer)

Comment: you don't have to you should accept it, or at least accept it when 3.5 comes out ;)

Comment: 3.5 is with me :)

Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Jan - Been offline over Christmas. Happy New Year.

I did get your way working thank you... however! I've had to change the way I use this now as I've added a meta field to posts and pages instead of using a page template.

I now have a meta field being saved from the admin area per post/page as "smartPrivate" with three (for example) possible values (1,2,3).

This way I'm hoping to filter results from a function using "pre_get_posts". I would like to run it as a function to avoid any template changes as we're building child themes.

Should I post this as a new question?

Comment: Yes I suggest a new question, you might wanna reference this one

Comment: new question here if you're able to help at all : http://bit.ly/UK1bnz (Happy New Year and thanks for your help so far)